# angular rails app not working after putting controller to seperate file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a rails app which uses angular in front end. I have put all angular files in app/assets/javascripts/angular. I have one template folder which has all the views and app.js

**angular/app.js**

```
app = angular.module("appname", ['ui.router', 'ngResource', 'templates']);

app.config([
    "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("home", {
                url: "/",
                controller: "homeCtrl",
                templateUrl: "angular/templates/home.html"
            })
    }
]);



app.controller("homeCtrl", ["$scope", "$state", function ($scope, $state) {


}]);
```

This works.. But when I try to move the controller into a different file it wont work and not showing any errors. Here is what I tried for moving it to different file

**angular/app.js**

```
app = angular.module("appname", ['ui.router', 'ngResource', 'templates', 'homeCtrl']);

app.config([
    "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("home", {
                url: "/",
                controller: "homeCtrl",
                templateUrl: "angular/templates/home.html"
            })
    }
]);
```

Created below file in angular/controllers/homeCtrl.js
**angular/controllers/home-ctrl.js**

```
app = angular.module("appname", []);
app.controller("homeCtrl", ["$scope", "$state", function ($scope, $state) {


}]);
```

Below are the `2 lines` I added to `application.js`

```
//= require angular/app
//= require angular/controllers/home-ctrl
```

Here is the full  `application.js`

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require angular
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree ./angular/templates
//= require angular/app         //added this now
//= require angular/controllers/home-ctrl    //added this now
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require toastr
//= require bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Could someone tell me what am doing wrong here??

**update 1**

I have created a simple app to demonstrate it
 https://bitbucket.org/flyingboy007/testapp

Here is the `html head`

```
<html ng-app="testapp">
<head>
  <title>Testapp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/custom.self-17e1d92ee5c6aa25c961b0247a2b58df305a162ba2c7adc73cebd70894923726.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/welcome.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-e80e8f2318043e8af94dddc2adad5a4f09739a8ebb323b3ab31cd71d45fd9113.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery/dist/jquery.self-4e239680527cb2d6016e15eb767e577a5ba6c75055937d62957773e43b8773a9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular/angular.self-3850d7602cc1968e02b0a500d063347fdc614035a5369947cc4ab853f83c1edb.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.self-4b9be280d80df92307d4ec9b5676ccd659934704c7bb336b471df211b497e840.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-rails-templates.self-f73a25f00ce684992b28562a01665855f2aabcedd405901b89b47873f76ca8d1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular/templates/home.self-1ff1a25416205b20e5874f674491c4f16757e7fc8c90493cc6a12e9ad9d9a200.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular/app.module.self-ac8420276da6899e4a9bef3944222f2fe38907f55db6662a265ed8450c90f98a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular/app.config.self-ce8605f70015d41a58b4efbbed8d49dda515ebd60d8156494bf676b2a9315a97.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular/home-ctrl.self-98b167d187c2b959e75a30e0f26b0adec7706c96b058240bc6a89174b867a638.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.self-3555752f8a930795ee9e56751a52e6871104ae85d01b3ab8363da3802a5ecc78.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.self-d8b7bd612b3dcfdefb7b5539b9d5848d66ccbd3e7af8bb8d48bfb3288aaa7be8.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.self-e74d33ba39500940a78d6fa4d2d64f6ca7fd86d60a2149641f7fde7ba711d8a1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.self-35d204878d906298e55bc24553e11fd89b980fc4ffe5792fe36af8c0da289c54.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.self-056c40532d9f0f126ec17e839f60c942f573fbd61a086e7f156306e3fc5e8c1f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.self-e56c2ffee4618411d43ecf15c89273f6223847ad756e1cd17545d04afa732ed4.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.self-62463080dba6b9d024ff0a3192da0e76eacbc683194f3395047c6f5cfa0acb59.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.self-52afd90e8ba97d9f08617a13986e8869d6c4a45751c0bff59a6f91241e722aca.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.self-dad0d5c377f9fae26394484535ebb23ccf68afae084f896af6ea4cdf8c9f6ae0.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.self-3b268d4cd8c79e46ded7392885f72f64ffb5b0d49948a12b8cf9779f6163e13a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.self-facdc69246a072acb927ded77ff655f7c27a518b9357fddd45d119fbc8a0ab9f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.self-210cff1fb4b72b71a29b5122180cb5937c8145cd13a934dc838280f1d9607a3e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-sprockets.self-fbfa5ad7d9aa0afe439ec4ff3883acc4cb92b62cb67c40d674320c9aa1d4642d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-e87806d0cf4489aeb1bb7288016024e8de67fd18db693fe026fe3907581e53cd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/welcome.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-b5567fb0cb73f9d4ecd4fa178bbc995d9efe2b53da5e5bf4ca587adb307de5b1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="aDiaoRdtCY5NkOmNLrNaq9nMxja4jcohyEhnohlT0FgR+Pjk56TuDUfchLX1AylzgWdzzNNM3+XLfBIBE95GBQ==" />
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Out of curiousity are you building on top of an already existing rails application? Or is this a brand new one?

Comment: @Katana24 It's an existing rails app. trying to make it angular as far as I can!!

Answer (score 1):

you are redeclaring your `appname` module, in your controller as well.

**angular/controllers/home-ctrl.js**

```
app = angular.module("appname", []);
```

instead of this you should it this way.

```
angular.module("appname")
.controller("homeCtrl", ["$scope", "$state", function ($scope, $state){

}]);
```

Notice the lack of square brackets.

I faced the similar issue once, fixed it this way.

Comment: I tried that but getting homeCtrl function not defined error now

Comment: Try wrapping your controller file in function like this. (function(){  angular.module("appname")
.controller("homeCtrl", ["$scope", "$state", function ($scope, $state){
}])
})();

Comment: I have created a simple app to demonstrate it. could you please have a look.. https://bitbucket.org/flyingboy007/testapp

Answer (score 1):

Following [John Papa's Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md), I would advise the following:

1. Have only one module definition
2. Avoid assigning variables to the module definition i.e avoid

   `var app= angular.module(').....`
3. Use getter style when defining `controllers`, `directives`, `services` etc
   e.g

`angular.module("appname").config()` or `angular.module("appname").controller()`
and not

`angular.module("appname",[]).config()` as the `[]` redefine the module

The code should be:

`app.module.js`

```
angular.module("appname", ['ui.router', 'ngResource', 'templates', 'homeCtrl']);
```

`app.config.js`

```
angular.module("appname")
.config([
"$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
            url: "/",
            controller: "homeCtrl",
            templateUrl: "angular/templates/home.html"
        })
}
]);
```

And finally

`home-ctrl.js`

```
angular.module("appname")
 .controller("homeCtrl", ["$scope", "$state", function ($scope, $state) {

}]);
```

Load The files in the order

1. `app.module.js`
2. `app.config.js`
3. `home-ctrl.js`

Comment: tried it but getting this error now   `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module appname due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module homeCtrl due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'homeCtrl' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Comment: Could you paste your controller code? probably check `angular.module("appname")` if it is consistent in the 3 files. Probably you did not edit the `"appname"` in one or more files

Comment: I have created a simple app to demonstrate it. could you please have a look.. https://bitbucket.org/flyingboy007/testapp

Comment: Could you show the `view:source` of your HTML to see whether all files are loaded correctly?

Comment: I have updated the question with the head file of the html